# Publish a zip file to Nexus (Maven) with Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus, progress-4gl, openedge

Say you have a PL file you want to upload to Nexus with Gradle. How would such a script look like.

group 'be.mips'
version = '1.4.0-SNAPSHOT'

In settings.gradle --> rootProject.name = 'stomp'

And let's say that the pl file is in a subdirectory dist (./dist/stomp.pl).

Now I want to publish this stomp.pl file to a nexus snapshot repository.

As long as you go with Java, then Gradle (just like Maven) works like a charm. But there's little documentation found what to do if you have a DLL, or a ZIP, or a PL (Progress Library).

Comment: Did you look into publishing file artifacts? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html#sec:file_artifacts

Comment: Yes, jar files, but also zip, ocx, dll, ...

Comment: The link i posted shows a txt file example

Answer (score 20):

I publish such artifacts for a long time. For example, ZIP archives with SQL files. Let me give you an example from real project:

*build.gradle*:

```gradle
apply plugin: "base"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

repositories {
    maven { url defaultRepository }
}

task assembleArtifact(type: Zip, group: 'DB') {
    archiveName 'db.zip'
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/libs/")
    from "src/main/sql"
    description "Assemble archive $archiveName into ${relativePath(destinationDir)}"
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact source: assembleArtifact, extension: 'zip'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username nexusUsername
                password nexusPassword
            }
            url nexusRepo
        }
    }
}

assemble.dependsOn assembleArtifact
   build.dependsOn assemble
 publish.dependsOn build
```

*gradle.properties*:

```python
# Maven repository for publishing artifacts
nexusRepo=http://privatenexus/content/repositories/releases
nexusUsername=admin_user
nexusPassword=admin_password

# Maven repository for resolving artifacts
defaultRepository=http://privatenexus/content/groups/public

# Maven coordinates
group=demo.group.db
version=SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: Thx, do you also have a best practice or example on how you differentiate between a snapshot and a release. We've seen that maven automatically takes care of this. Does Gradle also look at the artifact to be published? If it contains SNAPSHOT, then it should be published to the snapshots repository.

Comment: Yop, this is also possible. But you have to specified that 'snapshot' repository in publishing.repositories {}, then create new publication inside publishing.publications {} with '-SNAPSHOT' attached to artifact's version number.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Kotlin DSL, declare the artifact as show below:

```
artifact(tasks.distZip.get())
```

where `distZip` is the task that produces the zip file, which in the above example, is from the [application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks) plugin.